# Paste Data from clipboard is not working on Iphone

Tags: codenameone

I try to get data, a string, from clipboard with following code:

```
String s = Display.getInstance().getPasteDataFromClipboard().toString();
```

This works well on the simulator, but not on the hardware. On IPhone 6 I will get no data from clipboard.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method is not implemented in iOS at this time. There's [an issue on that](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1435) which I just scheduled (it was unscheduled before).

We didn't implement it because there are usually better ways to implement functionality that is usually implemented with this API such as URL associations and share API.

FYI it should be pretty easy to implement this with a [native interface](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html).

Comment: Interesting thing, if I doubleclick on a Textarea, there comes a cut and paste in black color. These are working, that means, I will get on a IPhone Hardware the text from clipboard. May I use the cut and paste from the Textarea with a button? I don't find a Textareafunkction in docs.

Comment: When you edit the field we switch between Codename One to native editing and try to make it seamless. So the native OS text editor has copy and paste functionality builtin which is what you see. That's not something we do. A long press will also open a magnifying glass on iOS etc.